# Visual Studio 2019 align cout << operator

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, indentation, auto-indent

I print multiple lines of output in C++ like this:

```
std::cout << "Line 1" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Line 2" << std::endl;
std::cout << "Line 3" << std::endl;
```

After doing this multiple times, I realized that the multiple occurences of *std::cout* is a bit repetitive. I want to do something like this instead:

```
std::cout << "Line 1" << std::endl
          << "Line 2" << std::endl
          << "Line 3" << std::endl;
```

However, I can't seem to vertically align the first **<<** operators of each line. In VS2019, it ends up like this:

```
std::cout << "Line 1" << std::endl
    << "Line 2" << std::endl
    << "Line 3" << std::endl;
```

How do I vertically align the first **<<** operators of each line without resorting to manually spacing them?

Comment: If you enable clang-format, then it will format your line that way be default, but only if the line is long enough.

Comment: @Hernan Jugar According to your description, as far as I'm concerned, it is impossible to align the first << operators of each line without resorting to manually spacing them. And I suggest you could try to post the requirements to [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion).

Comment: I don't have a good solution for this but I agree that it would be good for the Visual Studio formatter to have an option that automatically lines up lines starting with "<<".  This is automatic in emacs cc-mode.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
std::cout 
    << "Line 1" << std::endl
    << "Line 2" << std::endl
    << "Line 3" << std::endl;
```

Comment: This is fine, but I was hoping that the first **<<** occurrence is on the same line with _std::cout_.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write all this stuff I would recommend that you do it like this:

```
std::cout << "Line 1" << std::endl << "Line 2" << std::endl << "Line 3" << std::endl;
```

If you do it like that you don't have so much code of the same thing under each other and it's faster.

Answer (score 0):

Add a tab (or 2-3, for the following lines) before the first "<<" of each line.

```
std::cout/*(TAB HERE)*/<< "Line 1" << std::endl
/*(TABS HERE)*/<< "Line 2" << std::endl
/*(TABS HERE)*/<< "Line 3" << std::endl;
```

I realize this is slightly manual (and can leave a slightly weird spacing after std::cout), but it's the solution with the least effort for what you want.

Comment: Of course, this solves the problem.  Better would be to use spaces though.  Essentially, this is what we're left with.  But I think the OP was asking the IDE to do this for us.